# Send changes in my django model to a client service

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, socket.io, django-channels

Recently I received a demand on the company I work for. They wanted me to build a API using `django` that will give support a chatbot client. Basically It is supposed to work like that:
The API receives a JSON object, containing a `message_receiver` and a `message_body`, and it is send to the chatbot client that will handle all the "message-sending" stuff. Great! After doing some research I decided to, instead of going for a logic in which the client periodically pings the server in search for new messages to be sent, go for the inverse logic, in which whenever the server receives a message It would automatically emit an event for the client telling him to send the message.

For doing that, I stumbled in some interesting tools, like `socket.io`, and `django channels`. I particularly liked `socket.io` more. So before getting my hands dirty, I drew all the process and ran into a problem that I couldn't find a straight answer to on the internet, most of the tutorials I looked into focused on showing how the communication client-server works, but I couldn't find one that would clearly tell me how to make the communication between django app - server , so my problem is...

Is it possible to make a logic in which whenever my `django` model is saved, I emit a `signal` that will trigger a `event` and make the comunication server --> client via `websocket` using `socket.io`?

If you have a solution using `django-channels` they are very welcome!

Thanks a lot guys! I'm here if any extra information is needed.

Comment: you just want to get a json object of message when change in a model occur ?

Comment: Exactly @gamer. Not necessarily get a json but I want a event triggered whenever a instance of a model is saved.

Comment: did you checked  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders    ?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this via signal in your Model . define this function under your model

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def my_handler(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    ...

    if instance.is_approved:
        mail.send_mail(...)
```

Comment: I know how signals work, I just wanna make sure that you can access socket.io/my websockets features through it

Comment: yes you can import in models any thing  and use here :) . django  models are more then models .

Comment: thats why I showed you mail function . its 3rd party call